# FlashDevelop code completion AIR API

Tags: api, flex4, libraries, flashdevelop, code-completion

I haven't used FlashDevelop in half a year, and on returning (and updating it) the code completion no longer functions properly. I'm not entirely sure, but I think the code completion doesn't know the AIR library.

[image]

When pressing "Ctrl+Space" after typing "import" will only show me the classes I have already imported.
Pressing "Ctrl+Space" after typing "import f" or "import flash." returns no suggestions.
If I type of the import by hand, the class will successfully compile though.

- I have updated Flex, FlashDevelop, the debugger
- Code completion is activated
- I have set Compiler Options >> SWC Included Libraries to "Flex 4.6\frameworks\libs\player\11.1\playerglobal.swc"
- searched google and stack overflow for a solution
- I have tried shang's suggestions ([this](http://shang-liang.com/blog/configure-flashdevelop-code-autocomplition-for-air-api/) & [this](http://shang-liang.com/blog/update-configure-flashdevelop-code-autocompletion-for-air-api/) too)

and I'm out of ideas.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jake

Comment: One thing that is certain is that you don't need to add 'playerglobal.swc' to your project. In FlashDevelop you manage the player/AIR API version in Project Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+Space will show all the classes included in the classpath. Select an entry and it will generate the import statement.

Comment: No classes are shown/suggested. If I press Ctrl+Space on a new line it shows me the most basic syntax (break, case, continue, else, ..) but no classes. (If I press Ctrl+Alt+Space, nothing happens).

Comment: Then I'd suggest to uninstall FD completely, including user files in AppData, and reinstall. Also create a new AS3 project without fiddling with its configuration: it should just work.

Comment: Brilliant. Reinstalling FD did the trick. _I though updating would have been enough..._ Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry about that, sometimes updating causes issues.